# How can I Configure CloudFront for Path-Based Routing to Serve React and WordPress Sites?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am working on setting up CloudFront to route traffic based on the URL path to serve different content hosted on Amazon S3 and a WordPress site deployed on a specific IP address. Here's the breakdown of my requirements and current setup:

**React Application on Amazon S3:**

I have a React application and it's build I have uploaded to an S3 bucket. Whenever there's a new update in the React app, for that I have created a Dockerfile and in this I create a build of react application and upload it to the S3 bucket. The React app is hosted on S3 and I want to make it accessible via URLs such as from the s3 bucket there I have uploaded my React app build.

```
https://www.example.com/user*
https://www.example.com/signin
https://www.example.com/forget
https://www.example.com/signup
https://www.example.com/resetpassword
```

**WordPress Site:**
I have deployed a WordPress site on a specific IP address (e.g., 146.48.42.88).
All requests, including those for the homepage, should be directed to this WordPress site.

**Requirements:** I have configured CloudFront to manage traffic based on URL paths but it's not working. I want direct traffic to the React application hosted on S3 for specific URLs, like I have provided above.

And for all other requests, including the homepage, to the WordPress site deployed on the specified IP address. Implement path-based routing using CloudFront behaviors.

How can I configure CloudFront to meet these requirements?